# Is there a way to access private Google Calendar?

Tags: java, api, google-chrome, client, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access Google Calendar of a person with private calendar through Google Calendar API. All I have is their Client Id and Client Secret, but no success. Is there any way to access events from their calendar?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a *private* calendar that others cannot access it? Either way, please always add the code you've tried to your question. See [ask].

Comment: Client Id and Client Secret will not grant you access to some ones calendar.   It just allows you to create an application to use a google api and request authorization of the users of that application to access their data.

Comment: If i can get this valid question reopened i will give you a full anwser.